# how to avoid 'session break' in two panels

Tags: php

i am a student and i am new in php

i am working on my project

i have two panels in my website (localhost)
one is user
other is admin

in both panels i hace created sessions on all pages

on user panel:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
   header("Location: index.php");
```

on admin panel:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   header("Location: login.php?e=please+login+first");
}
```

now i have opened both panels
and problem is that if i logout from one panel then other panels also logout .

forexample if i logout in user panel as a user then my admin panel session automatically redirect page to login.php when i refresh admin page

is there any way to avoid this or how to avoid this.. please help me. i shall be thankful

```
here is my logout code

for admin side

<?php
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php?e=Logout+successfully");
?>

for user side
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php?l=Logout+successfully");
}
?>
```

Comment: What's your script for session logout?

Comment: It all depends on what your *logout* function does.  If you're destroying the session (i.e. `$_SESSION = array(); session_destroy();`), then of course you're going to log both panels out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not destroy the session, but only unset the corresponding key

`unset($_SESSION['user'])`

Comment: you mean i should use `unset($_SESSION['user'];` insted of `session_destroy();` in admin logout.php

Answer (score 1):

If you use `session_destroy()`, it will destroy the session cookie id. Destroy the variable will be a better way using PHP `unset()` function and you will not lose all sessions cookies.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use both panel login at a time in same browser at same Pc. and its also not possible you can login one panel at a time.. and when you will not open both panel in same pc in same browser your this problem will automatically solve...